# how to maintain production/debug flavors in node js project

Tags: node.js

I am working on a node js project, so is there any way through which 
I can maintain production/debug flavor easily? Just like when I am running node app.js with some command line option, it would switch from producton to debug or debug to production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually done with environment variables.

Usually it's called `NODE_ENV` and is set to `production` or `development` etc.

You can test it with:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Some frameworks like Express give you an easy access to that variable with: `app.env` - see https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

For more info see: https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html

You can also do more complicated scenarios with modules like:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/config